# Por que técnica de Deep Learning são divididas em três, conhecidas como CCN, DBN e Autoencoders?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

Li em vários artigos de revisão que os métodos de deep leaning são divididos em grupos das Redes Convolucionais, Máquinas de Boltzman e Autoencoders. Mas, nenhum desse trabalhos justificam o por quê da divisão.

Comment: Penso que isso seria o mesmo que perguntar, por que programação é dividida em linguagens... Não me parece uma divisão, mas sim meios para cada finalidade....

Comment: Essas são apenas 3 arquiteturas de redes neurais, mas não são as únicas. Temos as redes neurais profundas, as redes neurais recorrentes. Cada arquitetura tem uma finalidade diferente. Convolução trabalha bem com imagens, redes recorrentes com séries temporais, autoencoders para gerar um encoder.

Comment: Mas se existem outras arquiteturas por que Deep Learning é enderessada, geralmente, a essas arquiteturas?

Comment: Alguma referência @MagicHat onde posso confirmar isto?

Comment: Não tem porque pensar em referências, perceba que através de padrões constantes formam-se grupos, e para cada grupo existe uma tecnologia adaptada exclusivamente para esse grupo. Quando você entende que cada grupo possa conter um tipo de dado, tecnologias são desenhadas para otimizar a interação ....